# How to type a computed property name?

Tags: typescript

```js
const foobar = <T extends 'a' | 'b' | 'c'>(name: T) => ({
  [name]: name,
  [`${name}Copy`]: name
})

const result = foobar('a') // typeof result is { [x: string]: "a" }
```

How to type a computed property name here?

I want `foobar('a')` to return `{ a: "a", aCopy: "a" }` instead of `{ [x: string]: "a" }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly tell typescript about the return type

```
const foobar = <T extends 'a' | 'b' | 'c'>(name: T) => ({ [name]: name }) as Record<T, T>
```

Comment: I thought about using `Record` utility type. What if we need to return `{ [name]: name, [\`${name}Copy\`]: name }`? Can we cast it too so it would return `{ a: "a", aCopy: "a" }`? 

Comment: Yes we can! `as { [key in T]: T } & { [K in T as \`${K}Copy\`]: T} )` (thanks to Retsam19)